# Material-UI AppBar buttons collapse into each other on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have this **Appbar** component and it renders fine on **wide screens**, see below:

[image]

But on **smaller screens**, the buttons crowd into each other like below:

[image]

Even trying responsive `typography` has not resolved my situation.
**So, I think I need to implement a drawer for smaller screens.**
What would that look like in code?

Here is my code for the **AppBar**:

```js
import React from 'react';

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { logout } from '../../actions/auth'


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  appbar: {
    height: 0
  }
}));

const Navbar = ({auth: { isAuthenticated, loading }, logout}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (   
      <AppBar position="relative" >
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title} noWrap>Goal Book</Typography>
          <Button href="/goals" color="inherit">Goals</Button>
          <Button href="/profiles" color="inherit">Profiles</Button>
          <Button href="/dashboard" color="inherit">Dashboard</Button>
          <Button href="/" color="inherit" onClick={logout}>Logout</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a `CSS`, in this case `JSS` issue.
Look closer at your styling, and utilize the breakpoints effectively.

```js
// For wider screens
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  // ...
  // declare a class, 
  // and attach it to all your AppBar buttons (with React/JSX/html)
  appButton: {
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: { display: 'none', }
  },
  // declare another class, 
  // and attach it to a major button/icon that should appear on smaller screens
  // create a dropdown list that is actived by this menu button/icon (React/JSX/html)
  appMenu: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: { display: 'none', }
  },
});
```

This is what we are doing above:

- Make all those `<button>` elements disappear on a smaller screen,
- Create a "menu" button or `icon` that **only** appears on smaller screen,
- Implement a dropdown `<list>` (whatever you like) that appears 
  once that "menu"/icon is clicked/touched on smaller screens.
  Place the buttons that are hidden from the AppBar into this `<list>`